# "Unexpected token 'export'" error in Chrome, "export declarations may only appear at top level of a module" in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, import, module

In my snake.html file, I included main.js in module type

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Snake</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/snake.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="gameBoard"></div>
    
    <script src="snake/main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In main.js, I imported some variables and functions from snake.js

```
import {speed, update as updateSnake, render as renderSnake} from "./snake.js";
updateSnake();
```

In snake.js, I imported a function from input.js

```
import {getDirection} from "./input.js";
```

```
export function update()
{
    const direction = getDirection();
    for(let i = 0; i < snakeBody.length; i++)
    {
        let segment = snakeBody[i];
        segment.x += direction.x;
        segment.y += direction.y;

    }
    console.log("Snake updated");
}
```

Lastly, in input.js I have an exported function named as getDirection

```
let direction = {x: 0, y: 0};
let lastDirection = {x: 0, y: 0};
export function getDirection()
{
    lastDirection = direction;
    return direction;
}
```

I did not write full code here in order to simplify the problem. When i open snake.html file in browser with live server, i got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'" in Chrome. I searched through all results on google that i found, and no one worked.
(also in getDirection function, it says "'getDirection' is declared but its value is never read."
I really need help?

Comment: I added html file.

Comment: Hm… are you serving the page with Node.JS? Does it help if you rename and replace all `.js` by `.mjs`?

Comment: I use no library or framework. All i have is vanilla javascript.

Comment: But how do you access the file? Via `file://` or via `localhost` or in some other way?

Comment: There is an extension named Live Server in VS Code. I use it with firefox or chrome. Both gives me an error related to my usage as stated in topic.